# What is the most efficient way to write multi-dimensional arrays AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

Hey I'm new to Action Script 3 and I was wondering if anyone could way in on what the best method of creating a multi-dimension array was. I've seen different ways of doing it and don't know which one's work. I am working on a project and I want to store x and y coordinates with an index 0-11.

If anyone could help me understand the different methods or an efficient way to do that, that would be awesome thanks!

Comment: You will have to create an Array of length 12. From there you can... (a) In each of the 12 slots you can put a second Array with length of 2 ...or (b) In each of the 12 slots you can put a [Point object](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dca.html).

Comment: In general, a multi-dimensional array is an array of arrays, not a certain class. So you make an array of desired length, then fill it with arrays of 2nd dimension length, shold you need more dimensions, you fill those with more arrays. Then you can address a cell by `theArray[i][j]`.